# Facebook upload a picture using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium WebDriver I'm not able to click on add picture/video to a group in Facebook.

i tried

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@aria-label='הוסף תמונה או סרטון']")).click();
```

but it does not work.

I'm getting the error "Cannot click  elements"

How do I locate the element?

The html snippet is:

```
<div class="_3jk">
    <input aria-label="הוסף תמונה או סרטון" accept="video/*,  video/x-m4v, video/webm, video/x-ms-wmv, video/x-msvideo, video/3gpp, video/flv, video/x-flv, video/mp4, video/quicktime, video/mpeg, video/ogv, .ts, .mkv, image/*, image/heic, image/heif" containerclassname="_5g_r" multiple="" name="composer_photo[]" display="inline" role="button" tabindex="0" data-testid="media-sprout" type="file" class="_n _5f0v" id="js_14">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi which language is this ? you have to use selenium localization

Comment: Please mention the locale language your using, and programming language

Answer (score 3):

Hi you could try converting the local text to Unicode values first, use the below website to do that:

https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter

So the unicode character for :

**הוסף תמונה או סרטון** is

```
\u05d4\u05d5\u05e1\u05e3 \u05ea\u05de\u05d5\u05e0\u05d4 \u05d0\u05d5 \u05e1\u05e8\u05d8\u05d5\u05df
```

**Now use that value in your xpath:**

```
a=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@aria-label='\u05d4\u05d5\u05e1\u05e3 \u05ea\u05de\u05d5\u05e0\u05d4 \u05d0\u05d5 \u05e1\u05e8\u05d8\u05d5\u05df']"));
```

**But still your code won't work**

You are trying to click an input element , you should click the div element . Click won't work in input element.

Try using below locator:

```
by.xpath("(//*[@class=\"_3jk\"])[1]")
```

Comment: thanks, but it's still does not work. getting exception: Element <div class="_3jk"> is not clickable at point (633,238) because another element <div class="_3u15"> obscures it.

any other ideas?

Comment: You should add a wait , try adding 10 sec wait before clicking and see if it works .

Comment: solved thanks!!.
i detected the element by copying the xpath and not by class. thanks a lot!

Comment: @Yemi please accept the answe

Comment: Could you accept the answer by clicking the tick sign near to my answer (near to my upvote button)  @Yemi